# Increment session object variable throws error

Tags: php, slim

I have created a session variable to store some basic stats:

```
 $_SESSION['stats'] = array('likecount' => 0, 'failedlikes' => 0);
```

Further down I have a line which increments it:

```
$_SESSION['stats']->likecount++;
```

However, this throws the error `Attempt to increment/decrement property of non-object`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's an array, not an object, so use `$_SESSION['stats']['likecount']++;`

Comment: Sorry, I should probably go to bed and stop trying to think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dealing with an array, not with an object, so you should use

```
$_SESSION['stats']['likecount']++;
```